# how to post data and binary data using urllib2 in python

Tags: python, urllib2, influxdb

I essentially want to do this:

```
curl -X POST "http://URL?u=user&p=password" --data-binary @myconfig.json
```

with urllib2.

I found examples for sending just the user and password, or just the binary, but not both at the same time, and some contradict each other.

I am doing this to create an influxdb with a retention policy based on instructions here:

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.8/advanced_topics/sharding_and_storage/

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8086/cluster/database_configs/mydb?u=root&p=root" --data-binary @myconfig.json
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import urllib2
import json

url = 'http://url.com?u=user&p=pass'
data = json.dumps({'config':'configData'}) # your JSON File goes in here, as argument to dumps.
cont_len = len(data)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': cont_len})
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
response = f.read()
f.close()
```

That solves it!

Note that, with urllib2, you cannot specify the .json file. You simply put its content into the `json.dumps` function.

Comment: doesn't work, says HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

I'm going to add more info to the question.

Comment: Okay @GilZellner. Please do.

Comment: scratch that, looks like the mistake was on my end in the url creation. Thanks!

Comment: This works because the data in question isn't really binary data, it's json, which is a string.  If it was bytes, this wouldn't work.